# PHP, MYSQL secondary key

Tags: php, mysql

I can not understand what I'm wrong.
I'm creating an Android app, where people register to enter their phone number, then in another activity, they enter the name and surname and registration is complete.
The problem is that I have a Database with 2 tables, one called "Numbers" (the fields are ID and Phone number) and the table "Customers" (the fields are ID, Name, Surname, and idNumbers_fk).
I can not save the data in the second table, how do I manage the secondary key?
In the sense that you are associated with the primary key of the "Numbers" table, but I can not pass it its value in the ID field.
I have a PHP code to insert the data in the tables, but I do not understand why it does not work.

Can you help me?

Here's what I have in the DB :
NAME DATABASE: Test1
NUMBER OF TABLES: 2

TABLE 1 :

- NAME TABLE : Numbers
- FIELDS : ID (PK) and Phone_number (VARCHAR(20))

TABLE 2 :

- NAME TABLE : Costumers
- FIELDS : ID (PK), Name (VARCHAR(20)), Surname (VARCHAR(20)) and idNumbers_fk (Foreign Key)

Here is my PHP code for phone number registration (This works) :

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

include 'Test1config.php';

 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

 $Pnumber = $_POST['NumberPhone'];


 $CheckSQL = "SELECT * FROM Numbers WHERE Phone_number='$Pnumber'";

 $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$CheckSQL));

 if(isset($check)){

 echo 'Number already registered';

 }
else{ 
$Sql_Query = "INSERT INTO Numbers (Phone_number) values ('$Pnumber')";

 if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query))
{
 echo 'Registration Successfully';
}
else
{
 echo 'Something went wrong';
 }
 }
}
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This is the code of the PHP file that gives me an error, here I insert the data in the "Costumers" table, but it gives me an error, but if I remove the Foreign key from the "Costumers" table it works, why? Where am I wrong?

```
<?php

   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

       include_once("Test2congig.php");

        $first_name = $_POST['nameC'];
        $last_name = $_POST['surnameC'];


     if($first_name == '' || $last_name == '' ){
            echo json_encode(array( "status" => "false","message" => "Parameter missing!") );
     }else{

            $query= "SELECT * FROM Costumers WHERE Name='$first_name' AND Surname='$last_name'";
            $result= mysqli_query($con, $query);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){  
               echo json_encode(array( "status" => "false","message" => "User already exist!") );
            }else{ 
             $query = "INSERT INTO Costumers (Name,Surname) VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name')";
             if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){

                 $query= "SELECT * FROM Costumers ";
                         $result= mysqli_query($con, $query);
                     $emparray = array();
                         if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){  
                         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                     $emparray[] = $row;
                                   }
                         }
                echo json_encode(array( "status" => "true","message" => "Successfully registered!" , "data" => $emparray) );
             }else{
                 echo json_encode(array( "status" => "false","message" => "Error occured, please try again!") );
            }
        }
                mysqli_close($con);
     }
     } else{
            echo json_encode(array( "status" => "false","message" => "Error occured, please try again!") );
    }

 ?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: Anyway I would think your query fails because your INSERT into Costumers needs to include a value for the idNumbers_fk field, in order to satisfy the foreign key constraint. You need to associate the user with their phone number. It's not really clear why you don't just do this all in one step rather than asking the user to complete two forms? Also it seems from your table structure that many user accounts can be associated to the same phone number - is that what you want?

Comment: I do not use a single form because people register with "AccountKit" of facebook by entering their phone number and that's it.
Then they enter their personal data as Name and Surname.
A Customer is associated with a single telephone number.
Thank you very much for the link you gave me, but I did not understand how to solve the problem.
The secondary key must I associate it with the telephone number?
The field telephone_number I put it primary key, but without auto-increment right?

Comment: The link I gave in the first comment is not directly related to your problem, it's for fixing your security issues regarding how you are executing your queries, that's a separate issue.

Comment: " A Customer is associated with a single telephone number". In that case you need only a single "Customers" table which has the telephone number field already in it. You only need the foreign key relationship if you intend to associate multiple customers with the same number. If you don't want that, then it has no real value. Probably the phone number can be the primary key of the customers table to ensure it's unique.

Comment: What you really need is a way for the phone number entered to be passed to the next part of your process so that you can easily associate it with the rest of the user data (i.e. so you can update the row containing the phone number with the first and last name). I don't know how this accountKit thing works but I would imagine there must be a way to achieve that.

Comment: since table  "Numbers" is the primary table associated with a member registration,  the ID must be auto increment . in order to prevent that problem the ID for   "Customers" must not be auto increment , you must have the same id for a single user in both tables. so when you call a user by id , using the both tables, all results will come as expected.

Comment: ADyson thanks for your help, listen if I use only a table, it gives me error by not allowing me to enter the data because people first enter their phone number, so if it has already been saved, click on the login button and enter. Otherwise click on the button to register and enter the name and surname. The problem is that if I have all the fields in a table, it gives me error and does not save my data.
Can you suggest a solution to use only one table, taking into account that the number is inserted in task 1 and the first and last name in task 2?

Comment: Well I don't know what your error is or what code you used, but at a guess you'd probably have to make the name fields nullable, so they can be left blank in the initial insert of the phone number, and then updated via the second query. Or alternatively you design it so you don't actually save anything until they complete all the steps (you can keep the phone number in the session temporarily) - depends if you want that they can complete one form and come back to it another day, or do all the steps in the same sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Costumers` table, make the field `idNumbers_fk` default value to `NULL`. This way when you set no data to this field, it will be NULL, which is an acceptable foreign key value.

The reason it's failing is that very likely 0 is being inserted by default, and no phone numbers with id of 0 exists in your Numbers table.

A more broad answer to your problem however, is that you have to save the id of the phone number somewhere in your app, so that when the customer wants to add Name and Lastname afterwards, you use that phone id same time.

Like this:

```
INSERT INTO Costumers (Name,Surname,idNumbers_fk) VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name', '$phoneNumberIdFromSomeSessionOrCache')
```

`$phoneNumberIdFromSomeSessionOrCache` is the value you need to store after the customer saves the phone number...

Comment: well, that might prevent the error but it doesn't make for a useful solution - OP needs to associate the phone number with the user data.

Comment: @ADyson He has two separate process there, what you are talking about is another step. I am telling him what causes his problem there.

Comment: No it's not. Because the _first_ step is that the phone number is captured. Then the names are entered. Therefore it should be possible for OP to supply the phone number to the second query. But anyway read the comments above - the data structure is wrong based on the stated requirement, there is no need for a separate table and foreign key at all.

Comment: Thank you for the answer buckyBadger, I do not understand one thing though, how does the secondary key take the value from the primary key of the other table?
Does it all by itself or do I have to pass the value of the primary key in the "Numbers" table?

Comment: @S.Bruziches you'd have to pass it in. Otherwise how does it know which row of the phonenumber table to take the value from? I think you need to get a better grip on the broader concept of one-to-many relationships in general. But like I said you don't need a separate table - in fact right now your design is almost a security flaw because someone can potentially associate multiple customers with one phone number

Comment: @ADyson He can NOT save the number and the first/lastname at the same time, don't you guys read this post ? It's two different and independent steps.

Comment: @ADyson Ok, but I do not understand how the Query should be to pass the value to the secondary key.

If the primary key is the telephone number and is entered, is it automatically passed alone in the secondary key?

Excuse my ignorance, but thanks to you and buckyBadger I'm starting to understand.

Comment: @buckyBadger I never said at the same time, I said in the same table. Anyway have an upvote for solving the immediate problem and suggesting a better overall solution

Comment: @S.Bruziches " If the primary key is the telephone number and is entered, is it automatically passed alone in the secondary key? Excuse my ignorance". No you have completely misunderstood how this works and what table relationships are for. The key defines a link between the two tables. It says that the phonenumber in the costumers table must match one of the values in the phonenumber table. It does not automatically cause one to be populated from the other. Imagine you have 200 phone numbers in your phonenumbers table.The code cannot automatically know which one to associate with the new user

Comment: listen, would you have any site where this thing is explained? I ask you why you are an expert and for sure you have sites or sources to report to me.
For the moment I thank you for the help and explanations you gave me, I go to deepen the topic.

Comment: @S.Bruziches there are dozens, if not hundreds, of tutorials, websites, books etc regarding entity-relationship design and database normalisation if you care to google those phrases. Relational database design has been around since the 1970s, there is no shortage of information available if you look. I don't have any specific recommendation, there are so many choices.